# Azure RBAC - modularity and custom roles inheritance

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rbac

My team and I are handling hundreds of subscriptions that are belonging to different teams.
Many of them have different needs in terms of security, services to be used, etc whereas we, as a central platform, also make sure that everyone work with the same baseline (security, monitoring, automation, etc.).

We of course have a need to handle RBAC and we are using custom roles a lot. I was wondering if there was a way to create a custom role based on another one to benefit from "classic inheritance".

So I could create for example a role named "***basic_user***" that would contains a set of "***Actions***" and an "***advanced_user***" could have "***basic_user***" accesses plus additional ones, and so on with "***super_advanced_user***".

I know that Microsoft has designed it the opposite way so far, allowing us to assign multiple roles to a given individual/group, but for internal design reasons, we would like to stick to one role assignment for a given recipient (one AAD group containing all people accordingly to their role).

Is this something technically feasible/reproducible or does anyone heard about such a feature ? Or maybe is it something we should not consider because of some reasons you'd want to highlight ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature that you would like to implement as you described is not currently not available as you were already aware of this. But however you can post about this feature directly via this [link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/filters/new). It will reviewed directly by the Microsoft engineering teams and will respond.